# Generate code blocks in markdown by cat-ing over files

Tags: shell, scripting, markdown

Hello I am trying to `cat` contents of files in a directory and append them to a markdown file as a code blocks.

I am able to `cat` the contents of the files to a markdown document but unable to add backticks to the markdown file. The backticks do not appear in the file. I can get backticks to print if I type ``` printf "``" ``` in my shell but not in the following bash script:

```sh
files=$(find . -name "*.h" -name "*.c" -maxdepth 1)

for i in $files;
do
    printf "\`\`" >> report.md
    cat $i >> report.md
    printf "\`\`" >> report.md
done
```

Comment: What's not working? What's happening with the backticks?

Comment: sorry it prints it doesnt print the backticks to the `report.md` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `find` statement won't actually find anything. There aren't any files named both `*.h` **and** `*.c`. You need `-o` for **or**:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 '(' -name "*.h" -o -name "*.c" ')'
```

The backticks should be in the output file, no reason they wouldn't be. That said, do you mean to have 3 of them? Normally Markdown uses 3 for code blocks. They should probably also be on separate lines.

````
for i in $files; do
    echo '```' >> report.md
    cat $i >> report.md
    echo '```' >> report.md
done
````

You could redirect the entire loop's output all at once.

````
for file in $files; do
    echo '```'
    cat "$file"
    echo '```'
done > report.md
````

For extra robustness I'd suggest using `find -exec` run the actions on each file. That way file names with spaces and other weird characters won't trip up the script.

````
find . -maxdepth 1 '(' -name "*.h" -o -name "*.c" ')' \
    -exec echo '```' ';' -exec cat {} ';' -exec echo '```' ';' > report.md
````

Or you could skip `find` altogether and simply loop over the desired files. This is also safe in the face of whitespace:

````
for file in *.h *.c; do
    echo '```'
    cat "$file"
    echo '```'
done > report.md
````